# db2 setup for Mac

Tags: macos, db2

I am trying to install db2 for my mac.

I downloaded the package. When I run the script db2setup I get a blank setup wizard.

It says

```
/Users/sanjanaagarwal/Downloads/expc/db2/macos/install/db2setup: 

line 606: /tmp/db2.tmp.26264/db2/macos/install/../java/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

When I check the log it shows

```
Operating system information: Darwin Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~.13.0.0 
ERROR: The user name specified is invalid.
```

HELP.

Comment: Did you install xcode?

Comment: yup. i already have Xcode

Comment: Someone answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341171/how-do-i-install-db2-express-c-10-1-on-osx-mavericks

Comment: I ran into this problem because my user was in the admins group. I created a new, non-admin account and was able to install it there. The instructions had commands for making it available (basically just having an admin chown the folders, see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797 for the instructions I followed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 Express-C 10.1 for Mac was released in 2012, well before Mavericks.  It's doubtful that IBM has done any testing with Express-C on Mavericks.  It does not appear that the JRE you can get [from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) for Mavericks works with the installer.  I do not know if installing a JRE from Oracle will work better.

In brief testing I find that it appears to work, but you may find it easier to install using the text-based `db2_install` command rather than the java-based `db2setup`.  This will require some additional steps to manually create a DB2 instance (create user, execute `/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/instance/db2icrt`, etc.), but once you've done this you should be OK.