# How do I install db2 Express-C 10.1 on OSX Mavericks

Tags: db2, osx-mavericks

I have attempted to install db2 Express-C 10.1 on OSX Mavericks, but I get the error listed here:
   [db2 setup for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919819/db2-setup-for-mac)

Comment: Good answer, but why not post the answer in the linked question?

Comment: @Leons, I plan on adding instructions each time Apple update OSX or IBM update Express-C, so I wanted a consistent title for each set of instructions.  Thanks for crossing linking for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the steps I did to install db2 express C on Mac OSX Mavericks.

Note:  I did all the commands logged into my own user; when I needed to run as a different user, I used sudo.

### Steps:

1. Download DB2 express C from here:
   https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=swg-db2expressc&S_PKG=dlmacosx&S_TACT=100KG31W&lang=en_US&cp=UTF-8&dlmethod=http
2. Double click the downloaded file to untar and unzip it.
3. Modify system parameters with this command:

   `sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf`

   and populate with this information:

   ```
   kern.sysv.shmmax=1073741824
   kern.sysv.shmmin=1
   kern.sysv.shmmni=4096
   kern.sysv.shmseg=32
   kern.sysv.shmall=1179648
   kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
   kern.maxfiles=65536
   ```
4. reboot computer   # with great sadness I added that instruction.
5. Begin the install process with these commands:
   `cd ~/Downloads/expc ; sudo ./db2_install`
6. Accept the default path of '/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1'
7. Wait about three minutes for the script to run.
8. Note that a successful run ends in 'The execution completed successfully.'
9. create db2inst1 user using mac gui  (System Preferences -> Users & Groups).  Use Standard (Non-Admin) privileges.
10. Create the instance with these commands:
    `cd /opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/instance ; sudo ./db2icrt -u db2inst1 db2inst1`
11. Modify your profile with this command:

    `vim ~/.bash_profile`
       and add these lines (probably at the end of the file):
        PATH=$PATH:/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/bin
        if [[ -f ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile ]]
        then
           source ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
        fi
12. Log into new terminal window to get new settings from .bash_profile.
    Exit old windows to avoid confusion.
13. Initialize the sample database using this command:
    `db2sampl`
14. Start the database using this command:
    `sudo -u db2inst1 db2start`
15. Test the sample database using these commands:
    `db2 connect to SAMPLE`
    `db2 list tables`

If you need to connect to this database from a remote machine, or want to connect to this database using Java where the connection requires a host and port number, then follow the instructions to enable remove connections.  You can defer running these instructions until you actually need to connect in this fashion.  Without running these instructions you can connect using db2 command line, after running these instructions you will be able to connect with any number of tools that require a host and port number.

### Steps to Enable Remote Connections:

1. Update db2 to allow remote services using these commands:

   `cd ~db2inst1`

   `sudo -u db2inst1 db2 update dbm cfg using svcename db2c_db2inst1`

   The cd is necessary because the command needs to write to the current directory.
2. Add the service port using this command:

   `sudo vim /etc/services`

   and add this line as the last line in the file.  The actual position is not important.

   `db2c_db2inst1 50000/tcp`
3. Set that db2 should use tcp/ip using this command:

   `sudo -u db2inst1 db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP`
4. Stop and start the database with these commands:

   `sudo -u db2inst1 db2stop force`

   `sudo -u db2inst1 db2start`

   Note the `force` on the stop command.  That will drop any existing connections.  If you want to be kind to the users who are connected, do not use force and just keep retrying the command after asking the users to disconnect.  I included the force in the default instructions because it is likely that anyone following these instructions is the only user on the database.

### References:

- http://programmingzen.com/2009/01/20/installing-db2-on-mac-os-x/
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797

If you determine improvements to these instructions please post a comment.  I will get notified and make the change.

Comment: db2_install command is deprecated, you should start using db2setup. Ref: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0058736.html

Comment: Thanks Arkanoid, I am not going to change these instructions because it is still supported for 10.1.  However, when I create new instructions for Yosemite, I will use db2setup.

Comment: Up to date guide for installing DB2 on Mac OS Yosemite and El Capitan is available here. There are additional commands required to enable OS authentication without which DB2 will not start: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797

Comment: Getting the following error at step 10.                                                            The host name "Livecs-MacBook-Pro.local" is invalid. Using Mac OS Sierra

Answer (score 1):

Excellent instructions Leons!  FYI for those who ran into DB2 errors when following his step-by-step and his updated guide for El Capitan, this may help.

1) I got the following errors when running the above steps 13 & 14 as db2inst1 (I was not able to run step 13 with my Mac userid, it likely gave some other error regarding userId/password, can't remember):

> db2inst1$ db2sampl

Starting the DB2 instance...
  Creating database "SAMPLE"...
  Attempt to create the database "SAMPLE" failed.
  SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019

'db2sampl' processing complete.

> db2inst1$ db2start

SQL1652N  File I/O error occurred.

2) The errors were due to a locking issue that was somehow introduced:

2016-08-02-16.43.26.649406-300 I8390E1394           LEVEL: Error
PID     : 19747                TID : 4515377152     PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
EDUID   : 1                    EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 Common, Generic Registry, GenRegFile::Lock, probe:50
MESSAGE : ECF=0x900001DA=-1879047718=ECF_GENREG_UNABLE_TO_OPEN_LOCK_FILE
          Unable to open the lock file
CALLED  : DB2 Common, OSSe, OSSHFile::open
RETCODE : ECF=0x90000001=-1879048191=ECF_ACCESS_DENIED
          Access denied

3) Turns out in my ~db2inst1/sqllib there were 2 files that were somehow created under my Mac userid instead of db2inst1, and they were preventing db2inst1 from obtaining the registry lock:

-rw-r--r--   1 myMacUserId  staff      0 29 Jul 15:58 .global.reg.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 myMacUserId  staff     90 29 Jul 15:58 global.reg

4) Once I deleted these 2 files, DB2 was able to start successfully and create the SAMPLE database. :)