# Error in creating SAMPLE database in DB2 express in mac os mavericks

Tags: express, db2, osx-mavericks

I have performed the steps given here([How do I install db2 Express-C 10.1 on OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341171/how-do-i-install-db2-express-c-10-1-on-osx-mavericks)) to install the db2 in mac os(mavericks), but when I come to step number 13. i.e. to create a sample database it says:

bash-3.2$ db2sampl

Starting the DB2 instance...
  Creating database "SAMPLE"...
  Attempt to create the database "SAMPLE" failed.
  SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019

'db2sampl' processing complete.

Can somebody help me regarding this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to start the instance:

```
db2start
```

However, that is weird, and you should see the `db2diag.log` file that can be found at:

```
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/sqllib/db2dump
```

Take a look at that file, and put the error messages (not all) here.

Comment: Thanks @AngocA
when i perform 
db2start
it says: 
SQL1220N  The database manager failed to allocate shared memory.

The following is the error message in db2dump:

MESSAGE : ADM13001E  Plug-in "IBMOSauthclient" received error code "-2" from 
          error message " ".

Comment: Follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341171/how-do-i-install-db2-express-c-10-1-on-osx-mavericks and pay particular attention to the steps that modify the maximum settings for shared memory (step 3).