# How do I install db2 on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, db2, osx-yosemite

I have attempted to install db2 Express-C 10.1 on Mac OS X Yosemite using the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341171/how-do-i-install-db2-express-c-10-1-on-osx-mavericks), and I'm hoping that there is not much differences between those two OSes. However at step 13 , that is:

> 13. Initialize the sample database using this command:
>   db2sampl

I got this error:

```
Attempt to start DB2 instance failed.
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24"
"USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001

'db2sampl' processing complete.
```

I tried to use sudo but I got another error

```
Starting the DB2 instance...
Creating database "SAMPLE"...
Attempt to create the database "SAMPLE" failed.
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019

'db2sampl' processing complete.
```

Please help!

Comment: Simple web search reveals: http://lpetr.org/blog/archives/installing-db2-10-1-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the instance with the right user. Probably, it was created with another user. Please type db2ilist, in order to check the usernames where a DB2 instance has been created; change to that user and start the instance. You can also change the configuration in order to allow other users to start the instance.

Comment: I have tried that in the terminal in the home directory (the username is db2inst1) but the result is "command not found"