# Cannot db2start using DB2 Express in MAC

Tags: macos, db2

I am trying to user the command db2star in my new DB2 Express instance and I receive:

> SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.

Looking at db2diag.log I got:

```
2015-10-14-23.31.46.395310-180 I87772E394           LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 1980                 TID : 140735278235648PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: Renatos-MacBook-Pro.local
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleReleaseStStLockFile, probe:12463
MESSAGE : Released lock on the file:
DATA #1 : String, 40 bytes
/Users/db2inst1/sqllib/ctrl/db2strst.lck
```

I installed DB2 express in my MAC Machine (OSX El Captain) using the following guide:

[How do I install db2 Express-C 10.1 on OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341171/how-do-i-install-db2-express-c-10-1-on-osx-mavericks)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using DB2 V10.1 on my mac.
I have used it since mac OS 10.6 snow leopard.
And I encountered same situation recently and resolved with the same way that Renato tried.
Just sharing the capture from my dirty note.

db2diag.log

```
2015-10-15-22.17.13.185718+660 I6438E430            LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 15931                TID : 4515377152     PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: XXXXX
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2main, probe:1884
MESSAGE : SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
CALLED  : DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloRunInstance
RETCODE : ZRC=0x83000001=-2097151999


2015-10-15-22.17.13.186668+660 I6869E392            LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 15929                TID : 140735111885568PROC : db2star2
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: XXXXX
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleReleaseStStLockFile, probe:12463
MESSAGE : Released lock on the file:
DATA #1 : String, 40 bytes
/Users/db2inst1/sqllib/ctrl/db2stst.0000
```

After doing

```
$ sudo chown db2inst1 /Users/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/*
Password:
```

I could do 'db2start' successfully.

Answer (score 0):

A more up-to-date for [Installing DB2 on Mac OS El Capitan](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797) is available.

This is the crucial step:

Enable OS authentication. (You need to be an admin user to run these commands):

```
     cd /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security
     sudo chown root /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw
     sudo chmod u+rxs /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw 
     sudo chmod o+rx  /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just run:

> sudo chown db2inst1 /Users/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/*

where "db2inst1" is your DB2 user.