# db2 express-c installation on mac os sierra

Tags: database, macos

i had followed the steps for installing db2 on mac os sierra and i getting error while doing step 10 ([How do I install db2 Express-C 10.1 on OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341171/how-do-i-install-db2-express-c-10-1-on-osx-mavericks?answertab=active#tab-top))

So could you please help me with the issue.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: no i didn't find any solution